# Plotting with the Mittag-Leffler function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to plot the solution of fractional differential equations as shown in the photos below, The solutions are in terms of the Mittage-Leffler function, so I evaluated

```
Plot[{MittagLefflerE[v, -t^v] + MittagLefflerE[v, -3 t^V], {t, 0, 2.5}]
```

but it does not help me.

Can any one help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: What are the values of `v` and `V`?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have just made some minor errors in translating the results from the paper into the Wolfram Language. When I plot

```
With[{v = .4},
  Column[
    Plot[MittagLefflerE[v, -t^v] + # MittagLefflerE[v, -3 t^v], {t, 0, 2.5}, 
      ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {1, -1}]
```

I get

[image: plots]

which seems to reproduce what the paper shows.

Since it seems likely you are a Mathematica beginner, you might prefer this longer, more repetitive, form of the code

```
With[{v = .4},
  Column[
    {Plot[MittagLefflerE[v, -t^v] + MittagLefflerE[v, -3 t^v], {t, 0, 2.5}, 
       ImageSize -> Medium],
     Plot[MittagLefflerE[v, -t^v] - MittagLefflerE[v, -3 t^v], {t, 0, 2.5}, 
       ImageSize -> Medium]}]]
```

which gives the same output as the more concise code, but is easier for a beginner to understand.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help

Comment: @Jojo. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.